# Highlight Suggested Edits by Low Rep Users on Review Page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, suggested-edits

I have found that the suggested edits by low rep users (500 or less), generally do not follow the StackOverflow guidelines:

- Add content to the question that makes it worse, **or**
- Makes an opinionated change to an answer (for example, see this suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/99331) Note: It was rejected by the community.

I am proposing that the suggested edits by low rep users be made to stand out on the Review page so that approvers can zero in on and tackle these suggested edits early on.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how this would help at all. You should be looking at all of them carefully before voting, and I don't see how you'd read one differently just because it's statistically more likely to be a bad edit.

Why would you want to "tackle them early on?" It's not like the post shows the edit until it's rejected, there isn't any time pressure to reject a bad edit. If anything, the ones more likely to be improvements should be handled first, as a good edit getting approved is good for the site.

Can a mod / team member tell us if there is a significant difference in the accepted to rejected ratio for edits by anonymous, 1 rep, 2-500, and 501-1999 rep users? It seems like this could be definitively rejected if there isn't a significant gulf.